# Accessing data stored in Amazon S3 through Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

My goal is to make graphs from data within excel files that users have uploaded to Amazon S3.

I've already implemented the functionality for users to upload the excel files with Carrierwave, now I need to be able to access the data and make it presentable for use with a charting library (Highcharts).

The task that I am stuck on is directly accessing the data in S3 through Rails. Once the data is pulled it should be fairly straightforward to manipulate it with Highcharts.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html):

```
require 'aws-sdk'

# retrieve the access key and secret key
access_key_id = ENV["ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
secret_access_key = ENV["SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]

# create an instance of the s3 client
s3 = AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: access_key_id, secret_access_key: secret_access_key)

# get the bucket
bucket = s3.buckets['your-bucket-name']

# retrieve the objects
bucket.objects.each do |object|
  puts object.key
  puts object.read
end
```

Comment: Also, would there be security implications for placing the access key info directly into the function?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post a complete implementation. You're right; you shouldn't put your keys directly in the code. I usually [stick them in an environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300680/262125). I'll update my answer.

Comment: @LandonSchropp, I am getting AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied , created from aws newly key and secret added policy also , what I am doing wrong at s3 setup ?

Answer (score 0):

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('AWS_BUCKET NAME HERE')
bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/#{obj.key}", 'wb') do |file|
    s3.get_object( bucket:ENV[:AWS_BUCKET], key: obj.key , response_target: file)
  end
end
```

OR

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
s3.list_objects(bucket: 'AWS_BUCKET NAME HERE').each do |response|
  response.contents.each do |obj|
    File.open("#{Rails.root}/#{obj.key}", 'wb') do |file|
      s3.get_object( bucket: 'AWS_BUCKET NAME HERE', key: obj.key , response_target: file)
    end
  end
end
```

There is official [AWS-SDK RUBY](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem

[AWS SDK ruby official documentation for version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html)

For enviornment variable configuration you can [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or [dotenv (for development environment)](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or set in **~/.bashrc** file.

**Note:**

1. You need to create S3 bucket and get **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_I**D and **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**.
2. Before development you can test and access your s3 bucket data using [google chrome s3 browser extenstion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extended-s3-browser/ddmmmnnbkhpkgnkafpflhaoohifpdkmg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
3. Run command **source ~/.bashrc** or **. ~/.bashrc** file to reflect changes, if you store ENV variables there.

[Code Reference](https://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/downloading-objects-from-amazon-s3-using-the-aws-sdk-api-v2-for-ruby/)