# How to hide API key using Sinatra gem with Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, sinatra, environment-variables

I am a beginner programmer who is currently practicing with the Sinatra gem.

One of my projects is a simple weather app that tells users the weather in different cities. Now I would like to hide the API key I've been using, since I want to upload this site to Heroku. How do I go about doing that? I know that I will need a config.yml file. Where does this go? Does it need to go into a certain folder?

It is just as simple as sticking this in the config.yml file?

```
    weather_api_key: *api key here*
```

Will I need to put any additional commands in my server.rb file?Can anyone give me any pointers here?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways you can do that.

One is to use a file, which you'd add to your gitignore, the other is to use a environment variable, and then refer to that in your config file:

in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export WEATHER_API_KEY=*api key here*
```

in `config.yml`:

```
WEATHER_API_KEY: <%= ENV['WEATHER_API_KEY'] %>
```

You'll need to either manually refresh your bash settings (`. ~/.bash_profile`), or close your terminal window and open a new one for the environment variable to be properly set.

Comment: You're welcome :) Please accept the answer if it works you

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variables

[Heroku recommends this too](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

[Try this too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300680/5487345)

Comment: Thanks for the info, especially about the Heroku instructions!

Comment: Please don't simply post links to other pages, as these links can become invalid over time. Provide the necessary context so that your answer does not need these external references. See the "Provide context for links" section (and others) in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer